# Get authenticated User in API controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to fetch the Authenticated User's data in API controller. How to do that?
Here is my **API\CompanyController**

```
public function selected_company(){
        return Auth::user()->id;
    }
```

The error I got through HTTP request...
[image: Error Image Here]

Comment: let the controller method pass through a middleware like `auth:sanctum` or `auth:api`, depends on what package you are using for api authentication.

Comment: I have updated `return Auth::user()->id;` to `return auth('api')->user()` but also it is not working

Answer (score 1):

To convey the comment in a comprehensible manner,

Either your controller should have a middleware, like

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Or your route to the api should be passed through the middleware

```
Route::get('your-api-endpoint')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: Are you passing the API Token in the Headers ? `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Comment: Maybe you should read more about how to authenticate user and pass the tokens in header.

Comment: Will you please recommend the resource site?

Comment: https://dev.to/romanpaprotsky/vue-js-token-based-authentication-with-laravel-sanctum-3a84